# Search a label in p4 using description as filter

Tags: perforce

Is there any way to search for a label with particular words in Description of the label?

Ex : 
LABEL_1_0_1_STABLE //path/to/component Created by unknown

I want to search all the lables which have "unknown" in their description.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the -e or -E flags (case sensitive vs. insensitive) for the p4 labels command, e.g.

```
p4 labels -e '*unknown*'
```

See the [P4 labels documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/labels.html) for more info.

Comment: If you could tell us exactly how it's not working, we might be able to help.

Comment: What happens if you run "p4 labels -m 10", which will just return the latest 10 labels ?  If that doesn't work, you probably have Perforce permission issues.  If it does work, try playing around with the -e expression to make sure the filter string is correct.

Comment: I think the -e/-E filter is only on the **name** of the label, not on the **description** of the label.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a very nice and elegant solution but unless someone has a better one you might try to iterate over all labels and grep for your pattern:

```
p4 labels | cut -f2 -d' ' | xargs -n 1 p4 label -o  | egrep -e "^Label.*|unknown"
```

If you have many labels it takes a while of course.
Alternatively you could simply call `p4 label -o` on all labels and write the output into a file for easier searching.